# How can I convert GMT offset format from +/-h to +/-hh:mm in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The table stores this information in +/-h format (e.g. -6).

I want to convert it into +/-hh:mm (e.g. -06:00).

How can I change the format in my SQL query?

```
Select GMTOffset from dbo.Trip Where ID = 1
```

**Current Output:**

| GMTOffset |
| --- |
| -6 |

**Target Output:**

| GMTOffset |
| --- |
| -06:00 |

Comment: which rdms are you usimng every database systems has their own functions

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the datatype to DateTimeOffset(7), but I don't know what your original data looks like, if you only have +/- hour, then I guess you also need some string conversion. Can you share an example?

```sql
declare @DateTimeOffset DateTimeOffset (7) = '2023-03-31 01:45:00.0000000 -08:00'

select @DateTimeOffset
```

Comment: I'm not looking to change the underlying format, just the output on my query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

for this the values don#t need to be integer,  you could also use -6,75 to get a correct answer

```
CREATE TABLE vals (val int)
```

```
INSERT INTO vals VALUES (1),(-6),(-8)
```

```
select concat(format(floor(val), '00'), ':', format((val % 1) * 60, '00'))
from vals
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 01:00 |
| -06:00 |
| -08:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QzN4VF-V)